# Visualize BEAST ancestral state reconstructions

Tags: data-visualization

I have a Nexus file of the following shape, generated by the phylogenetics tool BEAST. In contrast with the example below, my file has about 100 taxa and 10000 different trees.

```
#NEXUS

Begin taxa;
    Dimensions ntax=93;
        Taxlabels
            adan1251 
            blag1240-nule 
            wers1238-marit
            ;
End;
Begin trees;
    Translate
           1 adan1251,
           2 blag1240-nule,
           3 wers1238-marit
;
tree STATE_0 = ((1[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.02243609504948792,2[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.02243609504948792)[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.01067010801410265,3[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.03310620306359057)[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.022661511629175332;
tree STATE_1 = ((1[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:1.02243609504948792,2[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.02243609504948792)[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.01067010801410265,3[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.03310620306359057)[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.022661511629175332;
tree STATE_2 = ((1[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:2.02243609504948792,2[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.02243609504948792)[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.01067010801410265,3[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.03310620306359057)[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.022661511629175332;
tree STATE_3 = ((1[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:3.02243609504948792,2[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.02243609504948792)[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.01067010801410265,3[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.03310620306359057)[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.022661511629175332;
tree STATE_4 = ((1[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:4.02243609504948792,2[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.02243609504948792)[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.01067010801410265,3[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.03310620306359057)[&recon_lexicon:cooked rice="00000000000001",recon_lexicon:mountain="000000000001",recon_lexicon:to die="00001",recon_lexicon:wall="00000001"]:0.022661511629175332;
End;
```

I would like to visualized the ancestral states shown in this file. Ideally, I would like to see bar plots like in this thermo plot
[image]
from the [R ape package screenshot collection](http://ape-package.ird.fr/ape_screenshots.html), with areas proportional to the "1"s in the bit strings in the metadata, but I would be happy with a quick visualization using some other out-of-the-box software right now.

Ape might be capable of this task itself, [but I don't know how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350870/using-ape-to-display-beast-ancestral-state-reconstructions)

I generally work with python, but among the python modules I know (ete3, DendroPy, Biopython, newick) none seems immediately and completely able to solve this task – ete3 not read Nexus files and only does visualization, not aggregation of the data from the trees, DendroPy could do the aggregation, but only manually, and does not write a format that could be easily visualized like this, and Biopython seems to do neither.

From the packages developed with and for BEAST, DensiTree can do this in principle, but does not show nice plots in the nodes, instead the branches above the nodes can be coloured. However, adjusting these colours is a tedious and not scriptable task, and my Nexus file is big enough to make it choke.